# PerformanceObserver cannot measure redirected requests timings

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have been using [PerformanceObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver/observe) to measure the timings of network requests. Although it fairly seems to be working, I found a few issues:

1. If a network request is redirected by a server (basically server returns the response header as `Location: "same-origin-different-url"`), resource timing only includes the time from the request is made to the server sends the response code 302. So, the redirected URL is skipped and, also it cannot be found in all the resource entries that are returned by `performance.getEntriesByType('resource')`. Also, another note is that `redirectStart` and `redirectEnd` attributes do not include the redirected URL time because it is redirected to the same origin [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/redirectStart). So, is there any way to calculate redirected URL timing?
2. Some network requests take some time for DNS Lookup and I can observe those DNS Lookup times in Chrome -> Network -> Timing window. However, the same requests are observed by the PerformanceObserver always return 0 on [domainLookupStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/domainLookupStart) and `domainLookupEnd`. So, the timing does not match with Chrome Network Timing Tool. Any idea on this?

I will be grateful for any help if anyone has faced those issues and found a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

After I did read the [documentation](https://w3c.github.io/resource-timing/#dfn-timing-allow-check) carefully, I found out that response headers must include `Timing-Allow-Origin` header. Otherwise, those attributes will return 0. After added this header by using Charles proxy, I did not see any issues.

> Cross-origin resources **MUST** be included as PerformanceResourceTiming objects in the Performance Timeline. If the **timing allow check algorithm fails** for a resource, these attributes of its PerformanceResourceTiming object MUST be set to **zero**: redirectStart, redirectEnd, domainLookupStart, domainLookupEnd, connectStart, connectEnd, requestStart, responseStart, secureConnectionStart, transferSize, encodedBodySize and decodedBodySize.
>
> **The Timing-Allow-Origin** HTTP response header field can be used to communicate a policy indicating origin(s) that are allowed to see values of attributes that would have been **zero due to the cross-origin restrictions**. The header's value is represented by the following ABNF [RFC5234] (using List Extension, [RFC7230]):